# 3 tier architecture Obj Issue

Tags: c#

Im pretty new to 3 tier arch. 
I've been reading questions around this topic here at SO and a user response, this page, helped me a lot with a quick an easy example. http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Three-Tier-Architecture.aspx

When it explains Business Layer and DAL, the example uses **objdt** but I don't see it initialized anywhere. It calls a method from DAL so I assume it's a DAL object but again, I can't see the initialization. Then the same object calls a SQL function which is not described in the example but I assume it should go in the DAL class.

Am I wrong or the example is missing something? It would clear my doubts to know what that obj is.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would guess a new instance is being created somewhere as needed.

Comment: did you try downloading their sample and checking code - http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Examples/Three-Tier.zip

Comment: @rs. I tried but I cant open it, some error while converting versions :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code, you'll see that `objdt` is of class `clsStudentData`. 
Its being initialized inside of `clsStudentInfo`

Here's the snippet: (BusinessLayer.cs).

```
public class clsStudentInfo
    {       
        clsStudentData objdt=new clsStudentData();
            ......
```

The example on the web page just doesn't show the whole class of `clsStudentInfo`

Answer (score 2):

business layer:

```
clsStudentData objdt=new clsStudentData();
```

data layer:

```
Create_Connection objdt=new Create_Connection();
```